# Create a button programmatically in a fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, button

I wish to generate a column of buttons inside a fragment in Kotlin from a database. For now I tried with just one button, but I cannot seem to do it without hardcoding it in the XML file. Here is my code so far:

```
class NotesFragment() : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false)
        //val root : ViewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, null) as ViewGroup

        val button_Id: Int = 1111
        val button = Button((activity as MainActivity?)!!)
        button.setText("Button 4 added dynamically")
        button.setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        button.setId(button_Id)
        button.x = 250f
        button.y = 500f
        button.setOnClickListener(this)
        view.add(button)

        return view
    }
}
```

I know I should probably look for the layout somewhere in this and do an addView with it... What is the next step?

Comment: you can directly get rootview from fragment xml and add into it using addView

Comment: You should create xml file for button and then add then whenever you want in your fragment.

Comment: How? Like this?
view.rootView.addView(button)

Comment: Yes and don't forget to specify a different button id for each btn,  if you will inflate from xml. Just call `button.setId(View.generateViewId())`

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

`view.rootView.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.button_container).addView(button)`